# How To Design Time Slot Based App

Tags: design, architecture, sql, nosql

I have got a responsibility of designing an app which allocates time slots for doctors booking.

The scenario is like, there'll be entry for doctors and their time slot for each days. For E.g.

```
Doctor1 | Mon - Fri | 10:00 - 20:00
Doctor2 | Wed - Sun | 18:00 - 20:00
```

Now, when people will search for doctors, I need to show the available time slots for bookings.

Bookings may be stored like

```
Patient1 | SomeDate | Doctor1 | 10:00 - 11:00
Patient2 | SomeDate | Doctor2 | 13:00 - 14:00
```

So on query I need data like...

```
Doctor1 | Date | AvailableTime
Doctor1 | Date | AvailableTime
Doctor2 | Date | AvailableTime
```

So here are my queries

1. First of all should I use NoSQL or SQL for this kind of architecture?
2. How should I store the time slots of doctors and already booked time slots of patients?
3. How should I fetch the next available time slots based on the information stored?

Preliminary I was thinking of .NET and SQL Server, but I don't think it's viable for such fast query performance. Also how should I relate these data specially the time slots?

Also for NoSQL, I'm not sure whether JSON based structures will be useful for querying the available time slots.

Please help.

Comment: Don't be afraid to implement most of the logic in the application only using the database's querying features to narrow down the rows to the date and doctor you're handling.

Comment: @CodesInChaos This is where I'm stuck. Preliminary I'm thinking of .NET and SQL Server, but then how should I find the available time slots by querying SQL server?

Comment: As I said in my comment, don't do it in the database. Just fetch all the relevant rows ordered by date and time and process them in the application.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Thanks. I got it now. But right now I'm unable to think of the logic to subtract the booked time slots from the available time slots and then showing the remaining available time slots in DB. But I'll work on it and will come up with new question in StackOverflow if I'm stuck. Thanks a lot again for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- This data can be expressed well in a relational database, so a document based database doesn't really offer an advantage
- Using the database's querying features to narrow down the booking to the doctor and date(s) you're interested in and doing the actual processing in the application should work well. There are perhaps a few hundred bookings per month and doctor, fetching all those rows is still cheap.
- If necessary you can always add a caching layer or denormalize information about fully booked dates. But I don't expect this to be necessary.
- The total amount of data will be quite small, so you probably won't need sharding
- Many NoSQL databases favour sharding over transactions, which is likely not a good trade-off for you since you won't need sharding.

Comment: Thanks. I got it now. But right now I'm unable to think of the logic to subtract the booked time slots from the available time slots and then showing the remaining available time slots in DB. But I'll work on it and will come up with new question in StackOverflow if I'm stuck. Thanks a lot again for the suggestion :)

Comment: Sort the bookings by time. Look at any two adjacent bookings. The time between the end time of the first and the start time of the second is still free. Also include the time between start-of-day and first appointment and end-of-day and last appointment. (you probably want to eliminate free times shorter than a threshold).

Comment: Looks really complex than what I have thought of. Anyway thanks for the help. I'll start working on it. Will let you know once I'm stuck. Another thing I can think of is, design the UI like Google Calender or sort and load the booked appointments slots. So the remaining white space is free such that user can click and fill his time slot. In that case I just need to check whether two of them is overlapping while creating appointment. I have got exactly such demo at https://code.daypilot.org/55027/asp.net-doctor-appointment-scheduling

Comment: If you treat the time during which the shop is closed as a pseuo-booking the code should become pretty simple.

Answer (score 3):

Unless someone has a really unique way of addressing this problem, I would think they would buy something already built because there are security issues along with established ways of doing this.

> First of all should I use NoSQL or SQL for this kind of architecture?

From an architecture standpoint, both will work, so consider security as a prime consideration for choosing one over the other. The technology is not the issue, but you better have access to someone who really knows how to secure data if you're building apps for the medical profession. Even if you live in a country without any legal restrictions, nobody wants to broadcast their doctor appointments, get double-booked or accidentally deleted.

> How should I store the time slots of doctors and already booked time
>   slots of patients?

The medical profession and people in it have been doing this sort of thing for a long time and probably a particular way. Make sure you get a lot of user input on this or you will run into trouble. Build your data structures in your application first and then design how those will be stored.

These kind of scheduling systems just end up creating available future time slots. You'll handle this pro grammatically in your app based on client needs.

> How should I fetch the next available time slots based on the
>   information stored?

To prevent a lot of empty data, put the appointments in a separate table with a link to the open time slot. This prevents a lot of empty fields: client, purpose, notes, etc. This is all based on that customer input you should be getting.

It's not that difficult to see if a record's Primary Key does not exist in another table (I prefer this to an outer join looking for a null foreign key because it shows intent - See SQL Below.) to determine which time slots have a corresponding appointment or are free. You're asking, "Give me the open time slots for this doctor(s) that do not have a corresponding appointment record."

```
Select * 
From OpenTimeSlot as O
Where Does Not Exist (
Select * 
from ClientAppointment as A 
Where O.PK_ID = A.FK_OpenTimeSlotID)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But time slots are not fixed. So I'm not sure how can I store the Time Slots in tables? What I mean is, as per the requirement different doctors can have different time slot. For E.g. DoctorA checks on Mon - Fri from 0800 to 1000 hours with time slot of 15 minutes for each patient. DoctorB checks Wed - Fri 1800 - 2000 hours with time slot of 1 hour for each patient. So you see the time slot is not something fixed across doctors. It's different for different doctors.